# My ListView Data Is Not Show

Tags: android, listview

I am struggling from `Listview` , how to add two value in this `Listview` first is big and second is small , i am using `CustomAdapter` but i can't add two value , `Listview shows` null values , How can i add two values ,i never put mdata in my Adapter please help me how to show listview?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Data> mData;
ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter> mCustomAdapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mData= new ArrayList<Data>();

    mData.add(new Data("g1", "its g1"));
    mData.add(new Data("g2", "its g2"));
    mData.add(new Data("g3", "its g3"));
    mData.add(new Data("g4", "its g4"));

    mCustomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row);


    listView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);
  }
}
```

**MyCustomAdapter.Java**

```
    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ContactsContract.Data> mDataVariable;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactsContract.Data> dataVariable) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDataVariable = dataVariable;

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        TextView bigText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.big_text);
        TextView smallText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.small_text);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Data.java**

```
    public class Data{
    String t1;
    String t2;
    Boolean isSelected = false;

    public Data(String t1,String t2) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    public String t1() {
        return t1;
    }
    public String t2() {
        return t2;
    }
    public Boolean getIsSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

}
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/big_text"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/small_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dslenglish.httpswww.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your `getCount()` returns 0. That's why. Make it return `mDataVariable.size()`.

Comment: @deepak-sagar check my answer , will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataVariable.size();
}
```

Instead of this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

> **EDIT 1 :**

You didn't set any data in your controls inside `getView()` method

you have to set data in your `Textview` inside `getView()` method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // set data here like below code
       bigText.setText(mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).getbigvalue());
       smallText.setText(mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).getsmallvalue());
       checkBox.setChecked(mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).getIsSelected());
}
```

> **EDIT 2**

make your `My row.xml` hight to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` like below code

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/big_text"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/small_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 3**

use this

```
mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,mData);
```

instead of this

```
mCustomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,R.id.big_text);
```

**EDIT 4**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        TextView bigText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.big_text);
        TextView smallText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.small_text);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

         bigText.setText(mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).getbigvalue());
   smallText.setText(mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).getsmallvalue());
   checkBox.setChecked(mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).getIsSelected());
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    if(b){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "chceked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });


        return convertView;
    }
```

**FYI**

here is good **[tutorial for listview](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)**

Comment: @DeepakSagar by the way you didn't set any data in your adapter class check again

Comment: i cant understand please help me how to get checked item value

Comment: i accepted your ans please help me how to get checked checkbox item value

Comment: @DeepakSagar like this `mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).getIsSelected()`

Comment: Toast.makeText(CustomAdapter.this,mData.get(position).getIsSelected() + " checked : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   error show on toast

Comment: try this **`Toast.makeText(mContext,mData.get(position).getIsS‌​elected() + " checked : ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`**

Comment: @DeepakSagar happy to help you

Comment: this is a random values how to use mysql database in this code what changes

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataVariable.size();
}
```

You should return the arraylist size in getCount() as shown above. Also use match_parent for width in listview. 
Also `ArrayList<ContactsContract.Data> mDataVariable;` change it to `ArrayList<Data> mDataVariable;`

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Data> dataVariable) {
this.mContext = context;
this.mDataVariable = dataVariable;
```

}

Initialize your adapter as

```
mCustomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter>(getApplicationContext(), mData);
```

Comment: mCustomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row);

Comment: how to put mdata when i use mCustomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,mdata); then error show

Comment: but how to toast when i click checkbox

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
mCustomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,R.id.big_text);
```

line to

```
mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mData);
```

also in adapter class

```
    @Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataVariable.size();
}
```

Comment: not working error show  mCustomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,mData);

Comment: how to to Toast on checkbox click

Answer (score 0):

fill data into your getview

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        TextView bigText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.big_text);
        TextView smallText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.small_text);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        bigText.setText(mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).getbigvalue());
        smallText.setText(mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).getsmallvalue());
        checkBox.setChecked(mDataVariable.contactDtoList.get(position).isChecked());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First change your `CustomAdapter` constructor because it has object of `Data` class is not made by you . But `ContactsContract.Data` which is different .

**Change these lines in CustomAdapter**

```
ArrayList<ContactsContract.Data> mDataVariable;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactsContract.Data> dataVariable){}
```

**to**

```
ArrayList<Data> mDataVariable;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Data> dataVariable) {}
```

and also return `Arraylist` size to display data .So make change in following method.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return mData.size();
} 

@Override
public Data getItem(int position) {
   return  mData.get(position);
}
```

Change this line in MainActivity

```
 mCustomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,R.id.big_text);
```

to

```
 mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context,mData);
```

Hope this will Help.

**Update :**
Add this code in `getView()` to get checkbox value

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"checkbox checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"checkbox Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
      }
 });
```

Comment: how to get selected checkbox value